# Pandas apply+dtype gives unexpected result

Tags: pandas

I have recently faced a consistency problem using pandas dataframes.
Say I have a dataframe with differents column types:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1,2,3], "col2": ["a", "b", "c"]})
```

I want to check column types by applying a function:

```
coltype = lambda col: col.dtype
df.apply(coltype, axis=0)
```

which surprisingly ouputs:

```
col1    object
col2    object
dtype: object
```

whereas, when I check separately on a column, I do get:

```
coltype(df["col1"])
dtype('int64')
coltype(df["col2"])
dtype('O')
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is it a bug?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need parameter `reduce=False` in [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
print (df.apply(lambda col: col.dtype, reduce=False))
col1     int64
col2    object
dtype: object

print (df.dtypes)
col1     int64
col2    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. Anyway I still wonder why you need that optional argument to get the expected answer...

Comment: There is some optimalization, I am not sure as i can explain it very well. But it need return `DataFrame` if use `reduce=False`.